# Selenium how to extract href and label name Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to pull the href and the data-promoname from the

> URL: 
>   https://www2.deloitte.com/global/en/pages/about-deloitte/topics/combating-covid-19-with-resilience.html?icid=covid-19_article-nav

[image]

I tried the code below but can only extract href under the class "promo-focus", but I also want to get the `COVID-19 Economic cases: Scenarios for business leaders` from `data-promoname`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www2.deloitte.com/global/en/pages/about-deloitte/topics/combating-covid-19-with-resilience.html?icid=covid-19_article-nav"
driver.get(url)

for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('promo-focus'):
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that using Python?

Comment: Yes. As described above, I also want to get the text of the article title

Comment: I expect to loop all the links and corresponding text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try using the text method to get the text.*

*Example*

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www2.deloitte.com/global/en/pages/about-deloitte/topics/combating-covid-19-with-resilience.html?icid=covid-19_article-nav"
chrome_browser.get(url)
for a in chrome_browser.find_elements_by_class_name('promo-focus'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
    print(a.text)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I expected!

Answer (score 1):

To get the value from *data-promoname* you can do this by using *.get_attribute* method. This method can be used to get the value of any attribute corresponding to its tag.

```
driver_path = 'C:/chromedriver.exe'  #the path to your chrome driver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
url_to_open = 'https://www2.deloitte.com/global/en/pages/about-deloitte/topics/combating-covid-19-with-resilience.html?icid=covid-19_article-nav'
browser.get(url_to_open)
for a in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('promo-focus'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
    print(a.get_attribute("data-promoname"))
```

If you are looking for the content being displayed on the page under the anchor tags, you can use *.text* instead

```
print(a.text)
```

Comment: Thank you. Glad to know that!